# Cygwin setup.exe reverts to older GCC version

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I've installed GCC 4.5.0-1 under Cygwin, but now every time I run setup.exe, the "New" fields for all the GCC components are set to 4.3.4-4. If I proceed to install any other package, GCC 4.5.0-1 will be uninstalled and replaced with GCC 4.3.4-4.

To avoid this, for each setup.exe session, I have to find the 8 or so GCC packages and click them back round to "Keep". Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of setup.exe's many design flaws. The best you can do is click on the 'Exp' button at the top right of the window to select test versions of all packages that have them available. Fortunately there aren't many of those apart from the toolchain. Alternatively,  click on 'Keep' to keep the installed versions of all packages, but then you miss out on updates.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the 'Exp' button before. It looks good. I will follow through with it on my next shopping trip.